# How do I know 四周 means "four weeks" or "all around"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 四周确诊420万人，拜登终于坐不住了

At first I mistook it for "people all around Biden", until I clicked the caption I realize it means four weeks.

Comment: Interestingly, Mr. Google got it spot on by translating 四周确诊420万人，拜登终于坐不住了 as "4.2 million people were diagnosed in four weeks, Biden finally couldn't sit still"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blunt answer is 'we don't' know.'

The simple answer is 'look into context.'

You pretty much answered your own question.

It reminds me of a post I made sometime ago

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?3,143206,143206#msg-143206

In a different context, 傷心地 could simply mean "sorrowly" as in 傷心地告別 (sorrowly say goodbye)

But it can be a term for "a place that evokes deep sorrow"

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, you can't figure it out until reading the whole sentence or paragraph.

Note that interestingly, there is a 同義字 of 周 - "週" which has the similar meanings, but 周 possess broader meanings.